# ember model rendering strange behaviuor

Tags: ember.js

While experimenting with ember and ember-localforage-adapter I noticed a strange behaviour.

```
ember.debug.js:4888DEBUG: Ember      : 1.12.0
ember.debug.js:4888DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.18
ember.debug.js:4888DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3
```

I have three models:

**/app/models/ledger.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),

  purchases: DS.hasMany('purchase', {async: true}),
  players: DS.hasMany('player', {async: true}),
});
```

**/app/models/purchase.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  amount: DS.attr('number'),

  ledger: DS.belongsTo('ledger', {async: true}),
  player: DS.belongsTo('player', {async: true})
});
```

**/app/models/player.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  balance: DS.attr('number'),

  ledger: DS.belongsTo('ledger',{ async: true }),
  purchases: DS.hasMany('purchase', {async: true}),
});
```

and a simple route:

**/app/routes/purchase.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('purchase', params.purchase_id);
  }
});
```

My experimental template is

**/app/templates/purchase.hbs**

```
name: {{model.name}}
<br>
amount: {{model.amount}}
<br>
player: {{model.player.name}}
```

and it works showing me all invoked attributes. But if I add another line like

```
name: {{model.name}}
<br>
amount: {{model.amount}}
<br>
player: {{model.player.name}}
<br>
ledger: {{model.player.ledger.title}}
```

it shows the name of the player for just an instant and never shows the ledger title. How should load in the store the requested record to have them available in my template?

Comment: Will you show the responses from server for all of the record requests?

Comment: If I had the opportunity to see how ember-data interact with persistent layer I would understand a lot more. Working with localStorage-like library  like ember-localforage-adapter prevent me from understand that iteration. In fact if I don't bump in a ah-ah moment I will build a back-end api just for this purpose. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to resolve `model.player.ledger` in `afterModel` hook:

```
afterModel: function(model) {
  var controller = this.controllerFor('purchase');

  model.get('player').then(function(player) {
    controller.set('player', player);
    return player.get('ledger');

  }).then(function(ledger){
    controller.set('playerLedger', ledger);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log("promise is not resolved", error);
  });
}
```

In template

```
 {{player.name}} | {{playerLedger.title}}
```

I think you could see why `model.player.ledger` is not resolved or it could be empty.

You have typo in `player` model. Should be:

```
 //app/models/player.js
 import DS from 'ember-data';
 export default DS.Model.extend({
   // ...

   ledger: DS.belongsTo('ledger', { async: true }),
   //not ledger: DS.belongsTo({ async: true }),

 });
```

Comment: thank artyc.. changed but same behaviour. Actually, I am not sure, but I think you can omit the name of the model when is equal to the name of the association.

Comment: Artych your workaround had success. Actually I only nedeed to set `player` and retrieve the associate ledger with `player.ledger`. I'll accept your answer but I'am not convinced that this is the ember-way to load associated record. As I come from rails ActiveRecord, I expect (I'd like) that ember-data would do that when needed. Maybe I am missing something big

Comment: May be ember can't resolve deep nested promices, so `{{model.player.ledger.title}}` doesn't work, but {{model.player.name}} works. It's not clear for me. If you somehow already have `player.ledger` in the store, (for example you've resolved `player.ledger` or find all ledgers  in parent route), `{{model.player.ledger.title}}` should work, without your `afterModel` hook.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/computed-property-on-async-property/7176) I added the property `payer` to the purchase model:

```
  payer: function(){
    return DS.PromiseObject.create({
      promise: this.get( 'player' )
    });
  }.property('')
```

to be used in the template instead of `player`:

```
<h3>show purchase</h3>

model.name: <strong>{{model.name}}</strong>
<br>
model.amount: <strong>{{model.amount}}</strong>
<br>
<br>
model.payer.name: <strong>{{model.payer.name}}</strong>
<br>
model.payer.ledger.title: <strong>{{model.payer.ledger.title}}</strong>
<br>
<br>
model.player.name: <strong>{{model.player.name}}</strong>
<br>
model.player.ledger.title: <strong>{{model.player.ledger.title}}</strong>
```

This approach is very similar to the one suggested by Artych but, maybe because of my Rails background, I prefer to access an associated record from anywhere by the model and not by the controller associated to the route

The following gif (download it if don't see the animation) show the behaviour of both:

[image]

Can someone explain what happen? Why `model.player.name` disappear at the time when `model.plyer.ledger.title` appear? What's the difference from the template point of view between `payer` and `player` considering that both return a *DS.PromiseObject*?